# jython ltrim a string after the first comma

Tags: jython

How can I ltrim a string and return everything after the first comma. For example: 
Tools - Hand,Hand Tool - Porta Power, Cylinder, 50 T 
I want to return: 
Hand Tool - Porta Power, Cylinder, 50 T
The number of letters vary before the first comma in the descriptions and there are multiple commas in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the part before the first comma (and the comma itself), use the [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method:

```
s = "Tools - Hand,Hand Tool - Porta Power, Cylinder, 50 T"
print s.partition(",")[2]
```

Output:

```
Hand Tool - Porta Power, Cylinder, 50 T
```